# SQL: Columns are same except of one content

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Table:

```
ID           TIME            AMOUNT
-----------------------------------
1              x                5
2              y                1
2              y                3
3              z                1
3              z                2
3              z                3
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
ID           TIME            AMOUNT
-----------------------------------
1              x                5
2              y                4
3              z                6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `SUM(amount)` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: `SUM()` that third column and add the remaining columns to your `GROUP BY` clause: `SELECT ID, TIME, SUM(AMMOUNT) FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID, TIME;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `sum` the amount for each group:

```
select ID, TIME, SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT
from table_name
group by ID, TIME
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6a75e7824f0f8bc261c3956fb5e6fb4)